# How to find fields,objects,class pages, related to an app?

Tags: app

Is there a way to relate fields, objects, class, visual force pages connected to an app?Would that be possible to segregation like that. If so how do we do it?

Answer (score 2):

If the connected app is there solely for oAuth access and is an external app then no (there would not be anything).

If the connected app is part of a managed package then yes.

- Setup -> Installed Packages
- click on the name of the package
- click on "View Components

Comment: Hi Eric what if we created our own app in our org.  Can we find a way to assoiciate the objects, fields. classes,trigger related to our app?